# How do I execute ajax call when start param changes in datatables?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am creating a table that could potentially host over a million records. I am trying to utilize Datatable's Server Side Processing features, but am struggling. I have built the server to retrieve 1,000 records on initial screen load. From there, I want to utilize the change in the start param to help me fetch more data for the user as they scroll through the page. My problem is, how can I fire an ajax call when user scrolls past 100 records? I want this to be based off of the start param that is automatically passed from the datatables to the server on ajax request.

I am trying to replicate the following:
https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Here is my Jquery...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var h = \$(window).height();
    $('#tablelist1').DataTable({
      bServerSide: true,
      bProcessing: true,
      ajax:"$ajaxURL"
      aLengthMenu: [[100, 250, 500, 1000, 1500], [100, 250, 500, 1000, 1500]],
      iDisplayLength: 500,
      fixedHeader:true,
      order:[[1, "asc"]],
      scrollY: h-400,
      deferRender: true,
      scroller:true,
      paging:true
    });
  });    
</script>
```

Comment: This is not typically how the DataTables server-side mode works. DataTables automatically sends a request for new data whenever the user performs a sort, or a filter, or moves to a new page (assuming data is paginated). Scrolling is not a part of that mechanism. Perhaps you may be more interested in [the scroller add-on](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/)?

Comment: Otherwise, maybe you can [edit] your question to help clarify the specific issue you are facing, ideally with a [mre].

Comment: Im unfamiliar with Scroller, but what I am trying to replicate is this example..https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: Thank you - I take back what I said about server-side and scrolling not working together. Clearly they can.